# Partial Derivatives of Nested Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $f(x(a,b),y(a,b))$ of functions $x$ and $y$ such that $x,y,f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How would I go about finding the partial second derivatives of $f$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a \partial b}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial b \partial a}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial b^2}$?

So far, I have followed my intuition and figured that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}$ would have the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2} =& \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} \\
&\text{chain rule} \\
=& \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right) \\
&\text{product rule} \\
=& \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)\\
&\text{simplify} \\
=& \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}\\
&\text{switch order of derivatives} \\
=& \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}}_\text{(don't really like this step)} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}}_\text{(don't really like this step)} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}\\
&\text{chain rule again} \\
=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2} \\
&\text{product rule again} \\
=& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right)^2  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)^2  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2} \\
&\text{switch the order of derivatives again} \\
=& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right)^2  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\right)}_\text{again, eh} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)}_\text{again, eh} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)}_\text{again, eh} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)^2  +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\right)}_\text{again, eh} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2} \\
&\text{simplify again} \\
=& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right)^2  + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}  +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}  +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)^2 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2} \\
\end{align*}

In order to do this, I have assumed that the second order derivatives are continuous, allowing me to switch the order that I take those derivatives, and I am sort of ok with that. The other second order partial derivatives mentioned would be similar to this, but I am still unsure of my work. Does this intuitive approach hold up mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation in the line with *don't really like this step* is not admissible.

We recall
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}
+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
or more verbose
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\left(x(a,b),y(a,b)\right)
&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x(a,b),y(a,b)\right)\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}(a,b)\\
&\qquad+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x(a,b),y(a,b)\right)\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}(a,b)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Everything is fine up to
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2} =\cdots= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   The first term at the right-hand side of (3) is in fact
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) \right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} 
> \end{align*}
>   which can be written more verbose as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x(a,b),y(a,b)\right)\right) \right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}(a,b)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We see in (4) it is not admissible to exchange the partial derivative operators but have instead to apply the same rule as in (1) resp. (2).

> We obtain from (3) by applying the rule (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}}& =\cdots\\
> &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\right) \frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2} +\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\right) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\,\frac{\partial  x}{\partial a}
> +\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}
> +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2}\\
> &\qquad+\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y}\,\frac{\partial  x}{\partial a}
> +\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}
> +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\right)^2
> +2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\,\partial y}\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}
> +\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)^2}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial a^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial a^2}}
> \end{align*}

In the last line we collect terms accordingly assuming the functions are continuous and we can change the order of partial derivatives.

Comment: Ah, I see. Right answer, wrong reason. That's why you should never show your work! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @JasonMeziere: You're welcome.